Does Spring AI need update with every new version of integrated model
Do we need to update spring ai or particular model dependency everytime whenever a new version of model is launched
Lets say if we gpt-4-preview is supported till spring-ai:0.8.1 then if gpt-4 version released or gpt-5 released then dependency needs to be updated?
If yes, what TAT we are expecting spring Team will take to release that
Did a POC on Spring AI and before using wanted to check if we won't be blocked in evaluating any new model depending on spring ai dependency release cycle

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The model used is a configurable property in Spring AI. It can be configured by spring.ai.openai.chat.options.model for OpenAI, for example. The model can be defined for each request too, as part of the ChatOptions parameter. For OpenAI, see OpenAiChatOptions used with the Prompt class.

It is likely to work because all LLMs work essentially the same way, with the same parameters, a prompt and a response that is streamed or a full response.
Unless something is hard coded or too tightly coupled to the model provider, you will probably not need to change the spring version.
But I suggest you keep up to date, especially with brand new libraries like this one.
